# What four-letter word can have ER or EST added to the end to completely change its meaning?

Tags: word, english

$\vphantom{why are you reading this?}$

Comment: I can add something to the body if it's necessary, but the question is entirely contained in the title.

Comment: The -er and -est forms of the word all three should have different meanings?

Comment: @Arcane: Yes. None of them should be related.

Comment: [Ever, Everer, Everest](http://9gag.com/gag/aD3zRrd/mt-ever-mt-everer-mt-everest)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

> TEMP, TEMPER, TEMPEST

Comment: I don't think temp counts as a word, maybe an abbreviation.

Comment: @Tony: A "temp" is a temporary office worker. It's derived from an abbrevation, but is now used regularly without a period indicating abbreviation.

Answer (score 5):

You could also consider

> RASH (a skin lesion)
> RASHER (thin slice of bacon)
> RASHEST (most reckless)

Yes, all three could mean different degrees of the last definition, but we do have words that can mean something totally different.

Comment: They *can*, but they don't always. In the accepted answer, none of them have related meanings at all.

Comment: **SPOILER** @Deusovi -- no, all three words in your accepted solution derived from the Latin *tempus* ‎(“time, season”).  If you add the word "bad" in front of the last two, it becomes more obvious.

Comment: @Malvolio: They mean completely different things though: an employee, a capability to withstand anger, and a storm.

Comment: @Deusovi -- they mean an employee who is there a short time, how you feel during a particular time, and the weather during a particular time.  Or those were their original meanings, they have drifted a fair amount.

Comment: @Malvolio: You've just added "during a particular time" to two of the definitions. While they were originally from a root meaning 'time', that was centuries (millennia?) ago. I have no qualms considering them different.

Comment: @Deusovi -- _I_ didn't add "time", they were there originally.  "Temper" originally meant something like "mood" does (and sometimes still does, as in "_in_ an ill temper"), and "tempest" mean something closer to "season" or "weather" than "storm".  Yes, they have drifted over the centuries.

Answer (score 2):

> Rath : (in Ireland) a strong circular earthen wall forming an enclosure and serving as a fort and residence for a tribal chief.
>
> Rather : used to indicate one's preference in a particular matter.
>
> [Rathest](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rathest#) : earliest. (obsolete usage)

Answer (score 2):

> CONF, CONFER, CONFEST

All three are in SOWPODS, even though the first is only listed as an abbreviation in every dictionary I've found. (The same can be said of the accepted answer). [The -EST form is an archaic verb form](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/confest) equivalent to -ESSED.

---

Other answers which don't quite meet the criteria but are interesting nonetheless are:

- ARCH / ARCHER / ARCHEST (if the first and second are read as nouns then it works, but they could also be adjectives related to the third)
- EARN / EARNER / EARNEST (the third is definitely unrelated, but the second is clearly derived from the first)
- CANT / CANTER / CANTEST (the third is in SOWPODS but I can't find a definition, unless it comes from an adjectival form of CANT)

Comment: +1, but "TEMP" isn't really an abbrevation - it started out that way, but is now frequently used as its own word meaning "temporary office worker"; no period at the end signalling an abbreviated word.

Answer (score 1):

How about...

> HON (A term of endearment), HONER (A whetstone for sharpening blades), HONEST

Or...

> DIV, DIVER, DIVEST

Comment: The title says four letters.

Comment: Damn, i was going for 2 letters next :-/

Comment: There are a few one-letter options too: *P* is probably the best, followed by *F*.